# What does each character's special do, and how do you trigger them?

Tags: lethal-league

Each fighter in *Lethal League* seems to have a different special ability which can be activated once the special bar is filled by a few hits on the ball.  For instance, Raptor's steam trading card describes the following:

> Raptor is a rookie in the Lethal League scene, hailing from the south. Though young, he’s very determined and fiercely competitive. His weapon of choice is a metal baseball bat and his special ability allows him to twist around and quickly hit the ball two times in a row.

I've seen this in action in the game.  I also know that it's triggered by double tapping attack on the ball.  I've figured out that Switch's special is triggered by tapping jump again while in the air, but can't really work out what it does specifically.  I've also seen Latch eat the ball during his special and become able to spit it out in any direction again, but I have no idea how to trigger this when playing as him.

What do each of the special abilities do, and how are they triggered?

Comment: Pretty sure the blue bars under the character blocks, up top during a match, show the buildup to your next special hit.  It should go up with each hit of the ball.  As for what each ability does, I don't know them all.  Everyone but Switch triggers them with a hit, Switch triggers from a mid-air jump.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To trigger each special ability, you must **tap the attack key again during hit-lag** (that's the pause before the ball actually moves again). The only character exempt from this condition is Switch.

Abilities are only activated this way when the blue power bar below your health bar is full, which will happen naturally after four hits of the ball.

Each character has a different ability that works in a certain way.

**Raptor:** Basic ability, allows you to skip hitlag and hit the ball twice. Not much of an explanation needed.

**Switch:** Switch's ability is different in the sense that it cannot be activated in the standard way of hitting the attack button twice. Instead, it can be triggered in three different ways, as outlined by [the wiki](http://lethal-league.wikia.com/wiki/Switch):

> **Switch can use his special in three different ways:**
>   Jumping and then jumping again while in midair, crouching and then jumping again, jumping during the hitlag created by an overhead smash.

This ability allows you to hit the ball at a predetermined shallow angle that you can change by holding a certain direction.

**Candyman:** Candyman's ability involves making the ball go through walls and show up on the other side for a brief period of time. This ability can continuously be kept up as long as he keeps hitting his own ball.

**Sonata:** Sonata's ability allows her to manipulate the direction in which the ball goes by hitting a direction until it collides with a surface.

**Latch:** After hitting attack during hitpause, Latch is able to catch the ball in his mouth and keep it there until the ball's original hitpause goes away, after which he spits it out in whichever direction you are holding. In other words, Latch himself becomes a cannon.

**Dice:** Dice's ability allows you to launch the ball in an arc that can be made wider or shallower depending on which direction you hold.